# Network connection: Make available to other users

Tags: network-manager

which configuration file controls the option "Make available to other users" in the Network settings?

For users, who are in the netdev group, this option is checked by default. I would like to change that.

Best,
Johanna

Comment: Just to be clear, I think it means other users of the current computer, not users of other computers.

Answer (score 0):

the "permissions=" line in the file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/foo.nmconnection
```